# ERROR:2339 the property 'setNativeProps' does not exist type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

whenever i use 'setNativeProps' in my code it won't work for some reason and its not just one code.It always show the error 2339 and im using typescript
I'm using react.js with expo on a donut chart
HERES THE CODE, PLZ HELP

```
    React.useEffect(() =>{
        const maxPerc=100 * percentage/max;
        const strokeDashoffset= circleCircumference - (circleCircumference *maxPerc) /100;
        animatedValue.addListener(v =>{
            if(circleRef?.current){
                circleRef.current.setNativeProps({
                    strokeDashoffset,
                });
            }
        })
    })
    return (
      <View>
          <Svg width={radius * 2}height={radius * 2} viewBox={`0 0 ${halfCircle * 2} ${halfCircle * 2}`}>
              <G rotation='-90 ' origin={`${halfCircle}, ${halfCircle}`}>
                  <Circle
                   cx='50%'
                   cy='50%'
                   stroke={color}
                   strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
                   r={radius}
                   fill="transparent"
                   strokeOpacity={0.2}
                  />
                  <AnimatedCircle
                   ref={circleRef}
                   cx='50%'
                   cy='50%'
                   stroke={color}
                   strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
                   r={radius}
                   fill="transparent"
                   strokeDasharray={circleCircumference}
                   strokeDashoffset={strokeDashoffset}
                   strokeLinecap='round'
                   />
              </G>
          </Svg>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I just realized that this kind of props is only used in js and not in tsx and now i have to convert the tsx components/variable into js code

Comment: This error means that the value type of the ref `circleRef` is `never`.  Where does that ref object come from?